# How do I open the interactive shell/REPL in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and I'd like to have a REPL that I can run single Python instructions in. I've found some [year-old Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-interactive-repl-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) on this that says select the View > Other Windows >  Interactive menu item, but there is no Other Windows item in my version of VS Code (1.44.2).

Does VS Code have a REPL feature, or do I have to run python.exe directly from the Terminal pane?

Answer (score 8):

You are looking at the wrong documentation. That's for **Visual Studio**, not **Visual Studio Code**. They are annoyingly similarly named, which can be confusing, but they are two completely different IDEs.

The correct docs for VS Code is here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

There is a section for running Python codes on the Terminal:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_run-python-code

You can use the standard Python console.

1. Install the [Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
2. Setup and [select the correct Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

   - Open the Command Palette then "**Python: Select Interpreter**"
     [image]
3. Next, highlight the line you want to run, then right-click
4. Select the **Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal**
   [image]
5. It should open up a Terminal panel and run your code in Python console
   [image]
6. You can then keep right-clicking > Run and it will execute on the same session

There's also an option to run the entire file.

See the [Run Python Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_run-python-code) section of the docs for more info.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can open the command palette and enter **python: Start REPL**

This will open the REPL.