# Is there Python Shell like IDLE in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle

I'm writing code in Python and using both the default IDLE and Visual Studio Code as my development environments. I was wondering if there is a interactive shell like the one in IDLE in vscode, where I can run code and then enter the variable name to find out its value. I've been having trouble finding a shell-like feature in VSCode, similar to IDLE's shell. Is there any way to use IDLE's shell functionality within VSCode?

I tried using the terminal to set up a simple interactive interpreter, but I encountered an error. Is the terminal not suitable for using as an interactive interpreter?

Comment: The interactive shell is a feature of python not the editor. Run `python` in the terminal in vscode and you enter the interactive shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open the interactive shell/REPL in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808776/how-do-i-open-the-interactive-shell-repl-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

Open a new terminal in vscode `` Ctrl + Shift + ` ``

Run the `python` command

Then you have an interactive python shell

```
Python 3.11.3 (main, Jun  5 2023, 09:32:32) [GCC 13.1.1 20230429] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Note: keybindings might differ on mac.

Comment: When I run Python code with f5, it's debugging so it runs on the Python Debug Console, how do I run it on the specified Python Terminal? I'm sorry in advance, I'm very new to this.

Comment: **Keybindings**. `f5` is debug. `ctrl+f5` or `alt+x` should be to run a python file, but it might not be set in your keybindings. Open default keybindings: `Command Palette > Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`, search for the keybinding you want, use google to find the specific name. To edit or change your keybindings, open user keybindings: `Command Palette > Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`, and add your keybbindings there. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: example: `"key": "alt+x",`
`"command": "python.execInTerminal-icon"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the interactive window:

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py*

You can also use the shortcut key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open an interactive terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Python Interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) is a nice mix between Jupyter and IDLE